# Why does javascript's forever loop blocks the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does typing anything on input#q hangs the entire page?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="q">
<input>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#q").keydown(function() {
    while(true) {
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9cw2pjym/

The behavior I would expect is that the thread handling that particular keydown event would block, but the page would remain responsive. I did the test because I was curious to know if that code would prevent the user from typing on input#q. However, it goes far beyond that: the whole page blocks (I tried it on Chrome, Firefox and Safari).

I went ahead and tried this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    while(true){}
}, 5000);
```

after 5 seconds the page hangs. No more interactions are possible. Shouldn't that be on a different thread as well? Is javascript and all other interactions with the page running on the same thread?

Comment: this is why, `while(true) {}`.. That is an infinite loop.

Comment: Doesn't your test confirm the answer to your question?

Comment: It sure is. I'm not sure if my question is clear, then. I know while(true) is an infinite loop. My question is more about how the browser works. Shouldn't that loop happen on a different thread from the rest of the page processing?

Comment: Are you ultimately asking the reason for the JS and UI to use the same thread? Otherwise you seem to have already answered your own question.

Comment: I'm looking for someone more knowledgeable of browsers to explain me what's going on. I have an assumption and my test confirms my assumption. Still, I have no proof as a browser looks like a black box to me.

Comment: After getting answers here, you'll still have no proof. If you want to know the reason for what you seem to already know, then I would imagine it's simply that user interactions with the page cause non-atomic operations that could provide the JavaScript with data in some partial state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically most user-interfaces and specifically web-browsers are single threaded. They give an apparency of multithreading by a fairly complex event model. But it will only do one thing at once.

However, since HTML5 this is not quite correct anymore, it offers support for running multi threaded using [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) for background computations.

Comment: WebWorkers provide background thread for computational work but if you need DOM manipulation, it has to be done in UI thread.

Comment: @gp Thanks, that would be more correct - I adjusted my post.

Comment: As I'm coming to realise everything on a webpage (apart from WebWorkers) executes on the same thread. That seems to include: all javascript, scrolling, any kind of use interaction really, and even animated gifs. All that executes in a single thread and competes for the same resource. Is that correct?

Comment: yes... everything you run in javascript (event handlers, dom manipulation etc) and even DOM rendering done by browser is done on the same thread. setTimeout, setInterval, async ajax calls these are executed by browser on a background thread, but the callback which is your javascript again, will be executed on UI thread only.

Answer (score 5):

javascript is single threaded. So, even though setTimeout starts a timer, the callback event is invoked on UI thread only. That's the reason after 5 seconds your `while(true){}` forever loop hangs the UI thread.